# ReactJS: Событие onClick внутри другого компонента с событием onClick

Tags: reactjs

Компонент имеет события:

```
<li onClick={this.ITEM_handleClick}>
  <div>
    <span onClick={this.ITEM_closeClick} >&#215;</span>
    <p>{text}</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

- **Вопрос 1:** Как отменить внешнее onClick при внутреннем onClick?
- **Вопрос 2:** Поможет ли вынос тега span в отдельный компонент?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При клике на одном из узлов DOM, событие `click` "всплывает" вверх по дереву до тех пор пока не достигнет корня или не будет отменено в явном виде.

React передает в обработчик события "синтетический" [объект события](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#syntheticevent), который, помимо прочего имеет метод `stopPropagate`. Этот метод (как и его нативный аналог) останавливает дальнейшее "всплытие" события вверх по дереву DOM. Вот как можно использовать этот метод на практике:

```
var Block = React.createClass({
    handleClose: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('close');
    },
    handleClick: function(e) {
        alert('click');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <span>Foo Bar Baz</span>
                <span onClick={this.handleClose}> &#215;</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

А вот и JSFiddle с [рабочим примером](https://jsfiddle.net/wcyrby1g/1/).